# How to match a hibernate/JPA table without a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to map a property (virtually) into the Entity linking to another entity that has no foreign key and without changing the database structure. There is already a getter for the key that maps to the related table.

An existing database.

Table egg

```
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| pid                  | varchar(60)      | NO   |     |         |       |
```

Table basket

```
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| pid                  | varchar(60)      | NO   |     |         |       |
```

The Entity Egg

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "egg")
public class Egg implements java.io.Serializable {
  private long id;
  private String pid;
  ...
  @Column(name = "pid")
   public String getPid() {
    return this.pid;
   }
```

The Entity for basket is similar with the pid getter already set as for egg.

I would like to model a join.

```
LEFT JOIN egg ON basket.pid = egg.pid
```

There is no foreign key on either table mapping pid together.

I have tried creating a basket property in the egg entity.

e.g.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName = "pid", updatable = false, insertable = false)
public Basket getBasket(
```

Of course hibernate complains that there is no 'basket' column in the table.

How do I get a the basket for this egg?

Comment: Isn't `@ManyToMany` annotation missing before `@JoinColumn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` annotation.

Something like this should work:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT b.id FROM Basket b WHERE b.pid = pid)", referencedColumnName="id")),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName="pid"))
})
private Basket getBasket() {
    return this.basket;
}
```